# How to combine multiple rows in a pandas dataframe which have only 1 non-null entry per column into one row?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am using json_normalize to parse json entries of a pandas column. But, as an output I am getting a dataframe with multiple rows with each row having only one non-null entry. I want to combine all these rows to one row in pandas.

```
currency    custom.gt   custom.eq   price.gt    price.lt
0   NaN 4.0 NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN 999.0   NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN 199000.0
3   NaN NaN other   NaN NaN
4   USD NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) (forward fill) and [bfill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) (backfill), which are methods for filling NA values in pandas.

```
# fill NA values
# option 1: 
df = df.ffill().bfill()

# option 2: 
df = df.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill')

print(df)

    currency    custom.gt   custom.eq   price.gt    price.lt
0   USD 4.0 other   999.0   199000.0
1   USD 4.0 other   999.0   199000.0
2   USD 4.0 other   999.0   199000.0
3   USD 4.0 other   999.0   199000.0
4   USD 4.0 other   999.0   199000.0
```

You can then drop the duplicated rows using [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and keep the first one :

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(keep='first')
print(df)

    currency    custom.gt   custom.eq   price.gt    price.lt
0   USD 4.0 other   999.0   199000.0
```

Depending on how many times you have to repeat the task, I might also take a look at how the JSON file is structured to see if using a dictionary comprehension could help clean things up so that `json_normalize` can parse it more easily the first time.

Comment: JSON structure:
{"and":[{"custom":{"eq":"approved_combination"}},{"custom":{"gt":5}},{"price":{"gt":2000}},{"price":{"lt":70000}},{"currency":{"eq":"USD"}}]}

Comment: ah, I think it doesn't work because your JSON has multiple dicts with the same keys and it's not nested in the way that `normalize_json` expects. Not a comprehension, but you could try something like this, which will nest it for you (this might not be worth it, though, depending on your use case):

Comment: `new_json = {}`
`for d in j.get('and'):` 
`for k, v in d.items():` 
`if not k in new_json.keys():` 
`new_json.update({k:v})`
`else:` 
`new_json[k].update(v)`

Comment: Thanks. It works for the case I commented. But for 
```
{"and":[{"custom_0":{"gt":4}},{"price":{"gt":999}},{"price":{"lt":199000}},{"or":[{"custom_2":{"eq":"combination"}},{"custom_2":{"eq":"top_brand"}}]},{"currency":{"eq":"USD"}}]}
```
How can I parse the json object with "or" key?

Comment: The above applies to each new key you want to process. Basically, you are just trying to make the dicts under the 'and', 'or', etc keys be nested rather than flat. So you can do an additional loop through for each top level key to recreate the list of dicts with those keys structure you already have. Then, take a look at the the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) about the `meta` argument.

Answer (score 1):

you could do

```py
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"a":["1", None, None],"b" : [None, None, 1], "c":[None, 3, None]})

def red_func(x,y) :
   if pd.isna(x) or pd.isnull(x) :
     return y
 result = [*map( lambda x : reduce(f,x), [list(row) for i, row in df.iterrows()]),]
```

Outputs :

```py
In [135]: df
Out[135]:
      a    b    c
0     1  NaN  NaN
1  None  NaN  3.0
2  None  1.0  NaN

In [136]: [*map( lambda x : reduce(f,x), [list(row) for i, row in df.iterrows()]),]
Out[136]: ['1', 3.0, 1.0]
```